# Reason Non linear Lineweaver–Burk plot

Tags: biochemistry, enzymes, enzyme-kinetics

V vs S plot looks like hyperbolic but 1/V vs 1/S plot is not linear at all. Looks like some kind of exponential growth. What can be the reason?

Comment: It is supposed to be linear as per the model. Are you talking about your experimental observations?

Comment: Without a graph and the data this question makes no sense. Like, 'my pcr didn't work, how come?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linearity of a Lineweaver–Burk plot assumes that your system follows standard Michaelis–Menton kinetics.

Not every enzyme system follows Michaelis–Menton kinetics with all the assumptions made in its derivation. There are a [number of reasons](https://facultystaff.richmond.edu/~jbell2/chapter-16.pdf) for non-linear behavior, including cooperativity, substrate inhibition, substrate activation, limiting cofactors, isoenzymes, and non-steady-state kinetics.

Further reasons for a non-linear plot involve experimental issues. Depending on your experimental setup, you may not have accurately measured the initial rates of some of the faster conditions, which can lead to non-linearity of your Lineweaver–Burk plot. If you're operating under conditions which may lead to product inhibition, you might also see non-linear behavior.